# What's Scala's OptManifest and NoManifest for?

Tags: scala, manifest, type-erasure

I'm learning Scala's concept of manifests and I have a basic understanding how to use it in some simple cases. What puzzles me is what's `OptNanifest` and `NoManifest` for? I've never seen then used. Can someone give an example where they're are needed/useful?

(I see that Scala 2.10 replaces the concept of `Manifest`s with `TypeTags` but until 2.10 is final we have to use `Manifest`s.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we have the following case class and type alias:

```
scala> case class Foo[A](a: A)
defined class Foo

scala> type F = Foo[_]
defined type alias F
```

We can now (not very usefully) make a list of things of type `F`:

```
scala> val foos: List[F] = List(Foo(1), Foo("a"), Foo('a))
foos: List[F] = List(Foo(1), Foo(a), Foo('a))
```

And we can turn this into an array:

```
scala> foos.toArray
res0: Array[F] = Array(Foo(1), Foo(a), Foo('a))
```

So clearly the compiler is able to find the manifest it needs as an implicit argument to the `toArray` method on `List`. But if we ask for a plain old `Manifest` for `F`, we get an error:

```
scala> manifest[F]
<console>:11: error: overloaded method value classType with alternatives:
  (prefix: scala.reflect.Manifest[_],clazz: Class[_],args: scala.reflect.Manifest[_]*)scala.reflect.Manifest[F] <and>
  (clazz: Class[F],arg1: scala.reflect.Manifest[_],args: scala.reflect.Manifest[_]*)scala.reflect.Manifest[F] <and>
  (clazz: Class[_])scala.reflect.Manifest[F]
 cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class[Foo[_$1]], scala.reflect.Manifest[_$1])
              manifest[F]
```

So it's clear that the compiler is having trouble using manifests to represent the wildcard in our type alias.

The reason `toArray` works is that it expects a `ClassManifest`, not just a `Manifest`. And in fact we can get a `ClassManifest` for `F` with no problems, precisely because `ClassManifest` uses `OptManifest` to represent its type arguments—unlike `Manifest`, whose type arguments are just other things of type `Manifest`.

```
scala> classManifest[F]
res2: ClassManifest[F] = Foo[<?>]
```

That `<?>` is the string representation of `NoManifest`. It plays the role of `None` here, allowing the compiler to represent the class information about the type `F` (which is all we need for creating an array, fortunately), without saying anything about the type arguments of `F` beyond "no, I can't model that".